# Finding the data center of a 365 tenant

Tags: office365

We have some function apps that works with our power apps and flows. We would like the function apps to be located on same data center as customers tenant. In the admin UI i can see the data location, but it only states EUROPE. How do I find the exact location (like West Europe, North Europe..) of a given tenant?

Comment: Use whois -> https://www.whois.com/

Comment: That just point to Microsoft root domain.

Comment: IP are not deterministic bound to geographic locations, you need to ask the owner of that IP where the data center is located.